# Fast calculation of min, max, and average of incoming numbers

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

Program is receiving approximately 50,000 numbers every second.

At ANY given moment, I need to calculate minimum, maximum and average of the values (numbers) that arrived in the last second (regarding to given moment).

Is there a way to do this without using array or list (buffer) to store arriving numbers and to calculate results?

If I need to use buffer, what would be the efficient way to achieve this?

(Note that numbers from buffer also must be efficiently removed from time to time)

Comment: Can you guarantee that the numbers arrive in order?

Comment: you say 'approximately 50,000' can it vary or are you unsure of the #?

Comment: It can vary, data arrives from external component...

Comment: @ademing, numbers are arriving in order but they are not ordered (like n1 < n2 < n3 < ...)

Comment: Do you need a running average, or is it sufficient to provide an average over the last complete 1 second interval? The latter is much simpler.

Comment: @Dusan, in that case, check out my answer. I believe it is definitely a possible solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that will somewhat work to save efficiency in certain cases:

1. As events come in, buffer them completely, and calculate a running `sum`, `count`, `min`, `max` (trivial).
2. When a request for `average`, `min`, or `max` is made, loop through from the back of the buffer and start removing values older than one second. Subtract from `sum` and `count` as you go.

   - If the values are all above `min` you can keep your `min`. If the values are below `max`, you can keep your `max`. In this scenario, you have `average`, `min`, and `max` updated efficiently.
   - If the values are below `min` or above `max`, you'll need to loop through the rest of the array and recalculate it.
3. Do step two once a second or so also so that the buffer doesn't get too full. This code could be performed on every buffer insert also, or wherever made sense.

Best structure for this kind of work is a circular buffer, to avoid memory allocations and GC getting in the way. It should be large enough to cover the worst case scenario for message size per second.

**Updates**

Depending on the usage scenario one other thing to do would be to run the algorithm above but in 10 x 100ms chunks rather than 1 x 1000ms piece. That is, keep the running min, max, sum and count on those 10 chunks. Then when you reach an 'invalidation' scenario, you generally only need to look through the latest 100ms of data or a quick pass through the min and max of the other 9 chunks.

---

@ja72 provided a great idea to save on finding the min and max values if they are invalidated:

Instead of keeping the min/max values x_min, x_max keep instead the index of where they are located in the x[i] array with i_min and i_max. Then finding them can be trivial sometimes, but when the last value considered holds the min and max, the entire list needs to be scanned to establish the new limits.

---

Sam Holder had another good idea in the comments - keep a parallel array that is always sorted, this lets you lop numbers off the top or bottom to find new minimums and maximums easier. However, insert speed here is compromised a little (needs to remain in order).

---

**Ultimately**, the right choice will depend on the usage characteristics of the program. How often will values be read vs how often they are inserted?

Comment: By using the interlocked queues in my suggestion, it's possible to never have to look for the min and max (the queue maintains them, and no work has to be done except when elements are added or removed), but you're probably right that in most scenarios the cost of allocating the nodes and maintaining a sorted list is more than having to look through the list again for the new max/min.

Comment: It will depend on how often a query is made. If not made often, inserts need to be cheap, lookups potentially expensive. And vice versa.

Comment: If I use circular buffer (one time allocated array in combination with lower and upper bound), does that mean that inserts and deletes(shrinks) are very cheap?

Comment: @Dusan: Inserts will be O(1).  Deletes can be O(n) if you pass a max or min.  Lookups may also be expensive.

Comment: If I am correct, finding index of the most recent element which is older than one second can be done using binary search?

Comment: @Dusan binary search works only on an array of SORTED elements.

Comment: They are sorted on time, so technically it is possible. Note that @ja72 below has a great trick for min/max that I've incorporated into my answer so people don't miss it.

Answer (score 6):

Use circular buffer with each element having timestamp and data, having maximum number of the elements per second as the size of the circular buffer.

As each element is inserted into buffer head, check for the expiration on the other side of the buffer, delete the element.

If the deleted element is minimum or maximum, you'll have to calculate new min/max.  If it isn't, you will update min/max according to the new arrivals.

For the avg, keep the total, keep the count, and divide.

Answer (score 3):

can't you keep a queue with your numbers and their arrival times, along with the current maximum & minumum values in the queue (will probably need to keep count of the number of values at the same min/max) and total value of all numbers in the queue and count of elements.

Then when a number arrives add it to the queue and adjust the min/max/value and count.  Then look at the other end of the queue and remove all elements that are not within 1 sec of the arrival of the last number, and again adjust the max/min/count/total value.

Then you don't need to keep calculate anything at an instant, just return the precalculated stuff (ie read the current value of min/max or total/count)

As @yaman pointed out you can't retain just the min and max as when one gets removed you might not know the new one.  in this case I would probably just keep a second copy of all the numbers in the list but rather than ordered by arrival time I would order by value.  Then you just add and remove each number from this list as well, so you'll always know the max and minimum values.  This saves you having to scan all elements in the buffer to find the new max/min, at the expense of keeping 2 copies, but updates to this list should be cheap as it is already ordered.

Comment: Count and total value are fine to adjust on the fly. Min and max can't be adjusted by removing values, since it takes a full scan of all values to find a new one when an old one is invalidated. My answer covers this worst case scenario.

Comment: Keeping a sorted list is overkill.  Instead keep some sort of priority queue, such as a heap.  Those take a logarithmic amount of work to get the max from, insert into, and delete from.  However you'll need one for the max and another for the min, so you need 3 lists.

Comment: @btilly Good suggestion to use heaps instead of a sorted list. Reading the max/min is O(1), it's removing the max/min element that's O(log n), because work is needed to maintain the heap. As pointed out in my answer for lists, you'd need to use a single node object per element (despite using two heaps and a list), so you can remove the elements from the heaps when you discover they've expired, otherwise deletes would be O(n) as you'd have to search each heap for expired elements. Using a single node means we know where the element is in each heap as we eliminate expired elements from the list.

Answer (score 2):

@DanRedux is correct; you will need to calculate them each time because your input is changing.  Now, you may prefer to calculate these numbers on demand or up front (i.e., when you get a new batch) depending on how often the results are needed.

For example, if your average use case polls for these stats every ~30 seconds then I would probably just calculate them on demand and cache the result until a new batch comes in.  It really comes down to your usage scenario though.

As for how to store them, you don't really have a choice, do you?  You need space for all 50,000 numbers in memory.  So... you need a chunk of memory large enough to hold them.  To avoid constantly allocating 2KB every time a new sequence comes in you're probably better off declaring an array large enough to hold the largest data set possible and just reusing it.  Again, this comes down to your requirements, i.e., do you know what your largest possible data set will be?  Does allocating a new chunk of memory ever second cause problems in your application over time?

Answer (score 2):

If the average of the last `N` values `x[0]` .. `x[N-1]` is `m_1` (`x[0]` is the latest value, and `x[N-1]` the last value considered) then the average `m_2` of the values pushing everything back by one index and adding the value `x` is

```
 m_2 = m_1+(x-x[N-1])/N;
 for(i=N-1;i>0;i--) { x[i]=x[i-1]; }
 x[0] = x;
```

Instead of keeping the min/max values `x_min`, `x_max` keep instead the index of where they are located in the `x[i]` array with `i_min` and `i_max`. Then finding them can be trivial sometimes, but when the last value considered holds the min and max, the entire list needs to be scanned to establish the new limits.

Comment: Great trick with minimum and maximum indexes, can be very handy!

Answer (score 2):

There's an efficient way to keep track of the minimum (or maximum) value within a given time window without *usually* having to store all the numbers that have arrived within that window.  (However, the worst case scenario still does require storing all the numbers, so you need to reserve space for all of them or accept that you may sometimes get incorrect results.)

The trick is to only store values that:

1. have arrived within the time window, and
2. are smaller (or larger) than any later value.

A suitable data structure for implementing this is a simple circular buffer storing values and their arrival times.  You'll need to maintain two indices into the buffer.  Here's a simple English description of the algorithm:

*At startup:*

- Allocate an *N*-element buffer `val` of values and a corresponding *N*-element buffer `time` of timestamps.
- Let `imax` = 0 (or any other value between 0 and *N*−1 inclusive) and let `inext` = `imax`.  This indicates that the buffer is currently empty.

*When a new value* `new` *is received at time* `t`*:*

- While `imax` ≠ `inext` and `time[imax]` is outside the interval, increment `imax` by one (modulo *N*).
- While `imax` ≠ `inext` and `val[inext-1]` ≥ `new`, decrement `inext` by one (modulo *N*).
- Let `val[inext]` = `new` and `time[inext]` = `t`.
- If `inext` ≠ `imax-1`, increment `inext` by one (modulo *N*); else deal with the "buffer full" condition appropriately (e.g. allocate a larger buffer, throw an exception, or just ignore it and accept that the last value was not correctly recorded).

*When the minimum value is requested:*

- While `imax` ≠ `inext` and `time[imax]` is outside the interval, increment `imax` by one (modulo *N*).
- If `imax` ≠ `inext`, return `val[imax]`; else return an error indicating that no values have been received within the time interval.

If the values received are independent and identically distributed (and arrive as a Poisson process), I believe it can be shown that the average number of values stored in the list at any given time is ln(*n*+1), where *n* is the average number of values received within the time interval.  For *n* = 50,000, ln(*n*+1) ≈ 10.82.  However, one should keep in mind that this is only the average, and that several times more space may occasionally be required.

---

For the average, the same trick unfortunately doesn't work.  If possible, you could switch to an [exponentially moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average), which can be easily tracked using very little space (just one number for the average and one timestamp indicating when it was last updated).

If that's not possible, but you're willing to accept a small amount of smoothing in the average values, you could calculate an average over, say, each millisecond.  That way, whenever an average of the values over the last second is requested, you can just take an average of the last 1001 millisecond averages, weighing the oldest and newest of them according to how much of those milliseconds lie within the interval:

*At startup:*

- Let *interval* be the length of the time interval to average over, and let *n* be the number of subintervals.
- Let *dt* = *interval* / *n*.
- Allocate an *n*+1 -element buffer `sum` of values and an *n*+1 -element buffer `cnt` of non-negative integers, and fill both with zeros.
- Let `prev` have any value.  (It doesn't really matter.)

*When a new value* `new` *is received at time* `t`*:*

- Let `i` = floor(`t` / *dt*) mod (*n*+1).
- If `i` ≠ `prev`:

  - Subtract `sum[i]` from `total` and `cnt[i]` from `count`.
  - Let `sum[i]` = 0, `cnt[i]`= 0 and let `prev` = `i`.
- Add `new` to `sum[i]` and increment `cnt[i]` by one.
- Add `new` to `total` and increment `count` by one.

*When the average value is requested at time* `t`*:*

- Let `i` = floor(`t` / *dt*) mod (*n*+1).
- If `i` ≠ `prev`:

  - Subtract `sum[i]` from `total` and `cnt[i]` from `count`.
  - Let `sum[i]` = 0, `cnt[i]`= 0, and let `prev` = `i`.
- Let `j` = (`i`−*n*) mod (*n*+1) = (`i`+1) mod (*n*+1).
- Let `w` = frac(`t` / *dt*) = (`t` / *dt*) − floor(`t` / *dt*).
- Return (`total` − `w` × `sum[j]`) / (`count` − `w` × `cnt[j]`).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there isn't. The reason why it's not possible is because you need to only account for them that are a second old, which means you have to re-calculate the result every time, which means HUGE loops.

If you wanted to calculate the last 40,000 numbers, or all of them, it would be easier, but because it's time-based, you have to loop through the entire list every time.

Comment: You only need to keep the last second worth of data

Comment: Just not true. See the other answers.

Comment: Agreed, there are clever ways to look at this problem.

Comment: It's impossible to avoid looping, is all I'm saying. Even just keeping the min becomes an O(n) problem, not an O(1) problem, as when the current minimum is lost, you have to scan the ENTIRE buffer of 50,000 values for the new minimum. It's possible to make it efficient, sure, but if you are limiting by time instead of a static number, then it's impossible to avoid the loop completely.

Comment: You only need to scan the last second's worth of data. Same amount of data each time you read it. Therefore, O(1).

Comment: Thanks DanRedux!
Can you tell me what would be the algorithm if I would have static number of elements, for example always 40,000?

Comment: David, that's the worst logic ever. It's still linear time, not constant, because to calculate the average you need to do a linear loop.
Dusan, if you always have 40,000 records, it's not too hard. For the min/max, start with an empty list, and any time you find a value higher or equal to the highest value of the list, append it to the list, and any time you lose a value, check if it's in that list and if so, remove it. This lets you maintain a sort-of-sorted list that is a lot smaller. Do the same for min. For the average, you remove/add the impact of numbers as you lose/gain them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this without using array or list (buffer) to
>   store arriving numbers and to calculate results?

No.  It's provably impossible to do this without storing the information, as you stated it.  You could tweak the requirements a bit to get rid of the need for a buffer though.

> If I need to use buffer, what would be the efficient way to achieve
>   this?

You'll want to use a Queue for this.

When an item is added, if it's the new max or min adjust those variables accordingly.  You can incrementally adjust the mean through the formula [here](http://jvminside.blogspot.com/2010/01/incremental-average-calculation.html).  Just Take the new value, minus the mean, divided by the new number of items in the set (i.e. size of queue plus one) and then add that to the old mean.

Then you'll have something more or less like this:

```
while(queue.Peek < oneSecondAgo)
{
  oldItem = queue.Peek
  queue.Dequeue();
  if(oldItem == min) //recalculate min
  if(oldItem == max) //recalculate max
  mean += SubtractValueFromMean(oldItem.Value, queue.Count);
}
```

To remove the value from the mean you should be able to just use the same formula for adding, but use the negative of the value rather than the positive...I think.  A better mathematician may need to help you out here.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are coming one after the other, then use a stopwatch and a while loop to get every number one by one for one second, and calculate min, max, and avg.

```
double min = double.MaxValue;
double max = double.MinValue;
double sum = 0;
int count = 0;
double avg;
StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
sw.Start();
while(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds <= 1)
{
   // Get the next number in the stream of numbers
   double d = GetNextNumber();

   // Calculate min
   if(d < min) min = d;
   // Calculate max
   if(d > max) max = d;

   // Calculate avg = sum/ count
   sum += d;
   count++;
}

avg = sum/count;
```

Then return min, max, and avg.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do without holding on to the numbers in a buffer or queue.

The reason for that is simple: when a maximum value expires (falls out of the 1 second window), the new maximum is some other number that arrived within the last second, so you need to have a record of the candidates that could become the new maximum.

Needing the average means all values have an effect when they expire, and nothing can be thrown out before it's one second old.

Sam Holder's suggestion of using a queue is a good one, though you'll likely need a specialized one that can keep your list in two orders simultaneously: the order in which the numbers were received (arrival time), and ordered from maximum to minimum.

Using a single node object with two next and two previous pointers (one pair temporally, and the other in terms of size) would make it possible to remove elements from both lists simultaneously, when an element expires from the temporal list, you have access to the pointers for the size list, because they're in the same node object.

The average can be maintained by keeping a running total and a running count, subtracting elements as they are removed, and adding them as they are created, so it is not necessary to iterate over the whole list each time in order to calculate the average.

As btilly suggested in their comment on Sam Holder's post, it would be more efficient to use a max heap and a min heap than to use a list, we would again need to use a single node with pointers for both heaps and the list, so we don't have to search for elements to remove them, and it might be necessary to spend some time considering how to properly remove elements not at the top of the heap, while maintaining the guarantee of O(log n) insertions and removals.

Answer (score 0):

For average, there are 3 cases to consider:

1. Your numbers are integers.  Keep a running total and count, add new
   values to the total, subtract old values from the total, and divide
   by the count as needed.  This is simple because you don't have to
   worry about loss of precision.
2. Your numbers are floating point and you require 0 loss of
   precision: You'll have to iterate over the entire one-second list to
   compute an average
3. Your numbers are floating point and you can live with some loss of
   precision: Operate as for the integer average, doing a complete
   recalculation every 1000 values or so.

For min and max (only relevant for #1 and #3 above):

- Keep the values in a treap indexed by value.
- Also keep the values in a doubly linked list ordered by time.  Save the beginning and end of
  the list.
- Remove from the beginning of the list, and add to the end of the
  list.
- For each new value: Add it to beginning of the time linked list. 
  Remove values as needed from the end of the time linked list.

As you add and remove values to and from the linked list, perform corresponding operations on the treap. To get a min and max from  the treap, just do find_minimum and find_maximum operations in log(n) time.  As you remove things from the right end of the linked list in constant time, also remove them from the treap in log(n) time.

Treaps can find their minimum value in log(n) time, find their maximum value in log(n) time, and find an arbitrary value in log(n) time.  In general, the more different ways you need to access your data, the better a well-rounded datastructure like a treap looks.